# Как получить Instagram access_token в правильном формате?

Tags: php, laravel, instagram, instagram-api

После авторизации в Instagram я получаю access_token но проблема в том что я получаю его в следующем формате:

/auth#access_token=token

Я пытаюсь забрать его из GET, но падает ошибка. Можно как-то получить токен вида /auth?access_token=...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ очень прост - никак, нужно использовать библиотеки для интеграции инсты с Laravel что бы уже в контроллере получать данные. Или можно заняться идиотизмом и js-сом выгребать адрес строки и получать ключ, но основня проблема ждет когда проходишь по ссылке - по факту в адресной строке появляются 2 одинаковых ключа.